# Python Syntax error while making a little game

Tags: python

New to Python and trying to figure out what went wrong here. Making a simple game in which I have to guess the number that was randomly generated by the computer. Thanks for your help.

Here's what I have:

```
guessed == random.randint(1,100)

print("I guessed a number between 1 and 100. Try to find it!")

entered = 0
while entered != guessed
    entered = raw_input("Enter your suggestion:")
    entered = int(guessed_number) 
    if entered > guessed
        print('Try less')
    else
        print('Try more')
print('You win!')
```

Comment: This isn't your syntax error, but you're also using the comparison operator where you actually want the assignment operator.

Comment: Hehe, there's lots wrong this. Every answer is right putting them all together and you should get it sorted, best of luck and happy coding

Comment: This may be a helpful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797350/control-loop-for-a-number-guessing-game-in-python/8797668#8797668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Python 3.x! Here's the fixed code for you.

```
#Import Random
import random as r


#Create a random Number!
guessed = r.randint(1,100)

print("I guessed a number between 1 and 100. Try to find it!")


#Initiate variable --entered--
entered = 0
while (entered != guessed):
    entered = int(input("Enter your suggestion:"))
    #Fixed your if/else tree with correct indents and an elif.
    if (entered > guessed):
        print('Try less')
    elif (entered <guessed):
        print('Try more')
    else:
        print('You win!')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the point of importing at the beginning?

Comment: if you don't import the class "random", you'll receive a... NameError: name 'random' is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing colons at the end of your conditionals and loops, aka `while entered != guessed:`. Add them to the end of the `if` and `else` lines as well. Also you are using the comparison (`==`) operator when assigning `guessed` instead of the assignment operator (`=`).

Also you will notice it prints "Try more" even when they guess the correct number, and then it will print "You win!". I'll leave this as an exercise to the new developer to fix.

Answer (score 3):

```
entered = int(guessed_number)
```

makes no sense because you don't have a guessed_number variable. I think you meant to do

```
entered = int(raw_input("Enter your suggestion:")
```

Also, you're missing colons after your block starts at while, if, and else.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list:

```
guessed == random.randint(1,100)
```

should be

```
guessed = random.randint(1,100)
```

I'm sure you'd rather assign to `guessed` than compare it `random.randint(1,100)` and then throw the result of that comparison away.

Answer (score 0):

```
entered = int(guessed_number)
```

It doesn't make any sense. There is no variable for 'guessed_number'.

I have edited your code to make it work:

```
import random

guessed = r.randint(1,100)

print("I guessed a number between 1 and 100. Try to find it!")

entered = 0
while (entered != guessed):
    entered = int(input("Enter your suggestion:"))
    if (entered > guessed):
        print('Try less')
    elif (entered <guessed):
        print('Try more')
    else:
        print('You win!')
```

Hope that helps!

~Edward